# How to split each digit in a given number with respect to their digit places?

Tags: c++

I was asked a question in an interview to write a program which splits the given number with respect to their digit places.

Input:

```
12345
```

Output:

```
10000
2000
300
40
5
```

Code:

```
int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;
int number;
cout<<"enter the number:\n";
cin>>number;

n1 = number%10;
number/=10;

n2 = number%10;
number/=10;

n3 = number%10;
number/=10;

n4 = number%10;
number/=10;

n5 = number%10;
number/=10;

cout<<n1<<endl;
cout<<n2*10<<endl;
cout<<n3*100<<endl;
cout<<n4*1000<<endl;
cout<<n5*10000<<endl;
return 1;
```

Comment: How about  you try something first and then come back and ask a specific question if you get stuck on something?

Comment: First try to think of the steps you need to take to solve this problem. Then try to solve each step, and if you get stuck at one step come back and ask a question about this specific step.

Comment: But i hv explicitly specified the digit places

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Longer strectches of code aren't very readable in comment markup.

Comment: Now that you have posted the code, do you see a pattern? Could there something be gained by switching from explicit variable names like `n1`, `n2`, `n3` and so on to an array with `n[0], `n[1]` etc.? (Take care: your output is in the wrong order.)

Comment: Coz m specifying 10 100 1000 explicitly how can v do without specifying these values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use a while loop so you wouldn't have to hard code the number of digits.  Your code is correct, although I'm assuming you need to print out the output in the correct order.  You could do this by keeping it in an array.  Instead of specifying each of the places by multiplying each digit by 10, 100, 1000, etc. , you could see that the powers of 10 correspond to each index when you are calculating the digits.

```
int number;
int digits[100];
int numDigits=0;
cin>>number;
while(number>0){
    digits[numDigits]=number%10; //Modulo ten to get the current digit
    for(int i=0; i<numDigits; i++){  //Loop through whatever digit you are on to retain the place 
        digits[numDigits]*=10;
    }
    number/=10;  //Divide by ten to get the next digit at the front
    numDigits++;  //Increment the number of digits by one
}
for(int i=numDigits-1; i>=0; i--){  //Print out the digits of the number backwards for desired output
    cout<<digits[i]<<endl; 
}
```